Error connecting Jmeter to Impala cloud server (LDAP) with JDBC
I am trying to establish JDBC connection with Impala Server using Jmeter 5.3.6.
Impala release 4.3
JDBC Driver: ImpalaJDBC41
JDBC Driver class: com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver
URL:
jdbc:impala://{host}:{port};AuthMech=3;SSL=1;UseNativeQuery=1;SSLTrustStore={truststore_location};SSLTrustStorePwd={pwd}

lib directory is added to Library as well as Impala Driver.
The error I instantly get is this:
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (\[Simba\]\[ImpalaJDBCDriver\](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Socket is closed by peer..)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0\]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0\]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731) \~\[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0\]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.initPool(DataSourceElement.java:308) \~\[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.6.3\]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.testStarted(DataSourceElement.java:128) \~\[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.6.3\]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:247) \~\[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3\]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:432) \~\[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) \~\[?:?\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) \~\[?:?\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) \~\[?:?\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) \~\[?:?\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) \[?:?\]\

Overall, seems like SSL is not working, but changing URL with SSL=0 gives the same error.
At the same time, DBeaver works fine with all the same settings and driver on the same machine.
I've tried change driver to Hive2, but at the end get same error.
JDK version change also didn't help (tried 21 and 11).

Perhaps you just missing a / in your URL after {port}? I think it is required by JDBC standard, to separate host-port from the schema and other optional parameters. And by the way, why are you still using 4.1 driver version? With the JDKs you're using, you should look to run 4.2.
